# Shell: How to a file's specified parent directory's name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am a beginner for Shell programming. I am currently writing a script to manipulate found files. but I would be needing to get the parent directories' names for found files. For example,

```
SEARCH_PATH=/home/test
for file in `find $SEARCH_PATH -name "pattern"`;
do
        echo $file;
done
```

in the search path there are several folders have the file pattern,

```
/home/test/type1/log/pattern
/home/test/type2/log/pattern
/home/test/type3/log/pattern
```

What I need to do is to find 'pattern' in those files, and also got the grandparent directory's name to the the 'type' name ...

Comment: You might be interested in `readlink -f filename`, this gives you the absolute path to filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dirty and quick:

```
kent$  dirname $(dirname "/home/test/type1/log/pattern")
/home/test/type1
```

if there is no `/` in your filename, you could also do with sed, awk cut.... one sed example:

```
kent$  echo "/home/test/type1/log/pattern"|sed 's#/[^/]*/[^/]*$##'                                                                                                          
/home/test/type1
```

**EDIT**

type only:

basename & dirname:

```
kent$  basename $(dirname $(dirname "/home/test/type1/log/pattern"))                                                                                                        
type1
```

with awk:

```
kent$  echo "/home/test/type1/log/pattern"|awk -F'/' '$0=$(NF-2)'    
type1
```

Comment: How could I get 'type1' only, rather than having '/home/test/' in the beginning?

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I expected. Might be dirty but working. :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a simple one, replace:

```
echo $file;
```

in your code to

```
echo "Found `basename $file` in `dirname $file`";
```

And see this as result...

```
Found kbd in /etc
Found config in /etc/kbd
...
```

Answer (score 1):

One generic solution:

```
SEARCH_PATH=/home/test
find "$SEARCH_PATH" -name 'pattern' | rev | cut -d'/' -f3- | rev

# Step by step explanations:
# 1. `find` Search all the files for the given pattern (e.g.: "/a/b/c/d")
# 2. `rev` Reverse each line (e.g.: "d/c/b/a/")
# 3. `cut` Remove the filename and the direct parent (e.g.: "b/a/")
# 4. `rev` Reverse each line again (e.g.: "/a/b")
```

Note I used double quote around `$SEARCH_PATH` to avoid bad expansion in some cases.